# how to create a list and then print it in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def list():
    list_name = []
    list_name_second = []

    with open('CoinCount.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        num_lines = 0
        for line in csvfile:
            num_lines = num_lines + 1

    i = 0
    while i < num_lines:
        for x in volunteers[i].name:
            if x not in list_name:  # l
                f = 0
                while f < num_lines:
                    addition = []
                    if volunteers[f].true_count == "Y":
                        addition.append(1)
                    else:
                        addition.append(0)
                f = f + 1
                if f == num_lines:
                    decimal = sum(addition) / len(addition)
                    d = decimal * 100
                    percentage = float("{0:.2f}".format(d))
                    list_name_second.append({'Name': x , 'percentage': str(percentage)})
                    list_name.append(x)
    i = i + 1

    if i == num_lines:
        def sort_percentages(list_name_second):
            return list_name_second.get('percentage')

        print(list_name_second, end='\n\n')
```

above is a segment of my code, it essentially means:

If the string in nth line of names hasn't been listed already, find the percentage of accurate coins counted and then add that all to a list, then print that list.

the issue is that when I output this, the program is stuck on a while loop continuously on `addition.append(1)`, I'm not sure why so please can you (using the code displayed) let me know how to update the code to make it run as intended, also if it helps, the first two lines of code within the txt file read:

```
Abena,5p,325.00,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.00,N
```

this doesn't matter much but just incase you need it, I suspect that the reason it is stuck looping `addition.append(1)` is because the first line has a `"Y"` as its `true_count`

Comment: why are you defining the function `sort_percentages` inside a for loop. Wouldn't it be best to define the function outside and use parameters to address whatever you want? Alternate, remove the definition and just have the actual statements inside the loop.

Comment: You are incrementing i outside the while statement. You should indent it inside so it can be incremented inside the while loop

Comment: You're also incrementing `f` outside the `while` block

Comment: `sort_percentages()` isn't even used